# S3 Static website give 403 forbidden access denied error when using urls

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a static angular website which I have published to an S3 bucket. I enabled the Static website hosting on the S3 bucket, and also selected all files in the bucket and did the "Make public using ACL" option. This should make the website open to the public to view.

When I go to the bucket website endpoint given to me under the Static Website Hosting section of the S3 Properties tab I can access my website just fine. All of the hyperlinks and routing work great. However, when I try to type in the url of one of the pages on the site I get the following error:

> 403 Forbidden
> Code: AccessDenied
> Message: Access Denied

Am I missing some kind of setup in AWS to allow for the urls to work properly? I did not setup or configure any other settings in AWS. Again, the entire website works as it should as long as I do not type in a url to go to other than the default page.

Here is an example of it working:

http://kh-mtc-app.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Here is an example of when you get the error. Even though the above link defaults to going to the same page:

http://kh-mtc-app.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dashboard

Comment: Please Edit your question to show us an example of a link that work and a link that does not work.

Comment: I have updated my question to include the links.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite strange -- if I go to the root URL, it returns an HTML page (looks pretty!).

Something changes the URL in the address bar, but I think that's done through Javascript rather than the browser actually *going* to the `/dashboard` location.

In fact, I found it in this line at the bottom:

```
<script src="main.898d7a46b746f05909f1.js" defer></script>
```

In that script, this line that appears to be changing the URL in the address bar:

```
const Dge=[{path:"",redirectTo:"/dashboard",pathMatch:"full"}
```

**Bottom line:** Your code is pointing to `/dashboard`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I found the answer and linked it to the question. There was an "optional" field under the S3 Static Website Hosting properties that I needed to update.

Answer (score 0):

After researching more on Stackoverflow I found the following which helped me out. [Angular S3 Static Website - 403 Forbidden Routing Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57642199/angular-s3-static-website-403-forbidden-routing-error)

Routing was working properly but typing in urls or refreshing pages caused errors. All I had to do was add index.html under the Static website hosting -> Error document property. That corrected the issues for me.